# Network Connection delay caused by TeamViewer service

Tags: windows-7, network-adapter, teamviewer

I have a device running windows 7 Embedded. When I boot it up, I find that it takes about a minute and a half to detect a network connection (or detect that none is available as the case may be), I get the blue circle on the network icon in the system tray

During this time, certain features aren't available (for example the "Tablet PC Input Service"), and if I try to "Open Network and Sharing Center", I get the frame of the window, but no information appears in it (e.g. like "Not Responding") until the Network connection completes its processing.

Here's the thing though, TeamViewer is installed on this device, and if I disable the TeamViewer service, then the problem doesn't occur! Unfortunately I need this service available for various reasons.

Any ideas on what could be wrong, and how to fix this?

**Edit**
I notice from the Event Logs, after the TeamViewer service starts up, I have the following events:

`The start type of the Tablet PC Input Service service was changed from auto start to demand start.
.
.
The Network Connections service entered the running state.
The start type of the Tablet PC Input Service service was changed from demand start to auto start.`

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this by setting the TeamViewer service to use "Delayed Startup"...

(i.e. go run `services.msc`, click on the Properties of the TeamViewer service and then set the startup type to "Automatic (Delayed Startup)".)

Still would like to know why this is happening though....